# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar valores de un programa para que se quede un registro aún después de cerrar y volver a abrir el proyecto?

Tags: java, eclipse

Aún no he creado el código, pues primero me gustaría saber como hacer esta función antes de idear la estructura

Comment: Tenes que persistir los valores. Lo común sería en un archivo o en una base de datos. También hay alternativas en la nube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te ha dicho Juan puedes usar tanto ficheros como bases de datos o soluciones en la nube. En caso de querer guardar un Log de la ejecución del programa se recomienda usar ficheros .log o .txt si quieres algo más rudimentario. 
Para crear Ficheros en Java y escribirlos durante la ejecución del programa hay muchas alternativas. Te incluye aquí una para que te hagas una idea:

```
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("./file/path/file.log"), true));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("line one\n");
    sb.append("line two\n");
    .
    .
    .
    sb.append("line n\n");
    pw.write(sb.toString());
    pw.close();
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Buena opción pero no debes generar respuestas tan elaboradas cuando la pregunta no es correcta ni concreta o no presenta intento previo, saludos.